# Multiple versions of VS Code on Apple Mac

Tags: macos

VS Code 1.15.0 and 1.15.1 
macOS 10.12.6

Hello, I seem to have managed to install multiple versions of VS Code. I currently have 1.15.0 and 1.15.1. These can be accessed separately by right clicking a file in macOS Finder and selecting either version. However, only one copy of VS Code is showing up in Applications and that seems to be 1.15.0. I've downloaded the latest Darwin build but before installing that, I'd like to get things cleared up so that I don't end up with three versions installed!

Comment: got the exact same problem here!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution (taken from Stack Overflow [Several versions of VSCode after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034028/several-versions-of-vscode-after-update)):

> #### Locate the other versions
>
> You can just run each of them, right-click on the Dock icon of the running version and select *Options* → *Show in Finder*.
>
> My versions were located here at
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Application Support/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/update.OhD5XFk
> ```
>
> #### Delete it
>
> Just delete the whole directory `update.OhD5XFk`